# argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_mainWindow'

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to make a GUI for a small program I wrote with the help of some people from here, anyway, I made the GUI in PyQt and it looks fine. I added a button called dirButton that says "Choose Directory"

```
self.dirButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.buttonWidget)
self.dirButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 91, 61))
self.dirButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("dirButton"))
self.dirButton.clicked.connect(self.browse)
```

and in the bottom line there I've made it call self.browse when I click it, which is:

```
def browse(self):
    filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '.')
    fname = open(filename)
    data = fname.read()
    self.textEdit.setText(data)
    fname.close()
```

However, this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\python-tumblr-0.1\antearaGUI.py", line 88, in browse
filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '.')
TypeError: QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(QWidget parent=None, QString caption=QString(),     QString directory=QString(), QString filter=QString(), QString selectedFilter=None, QFileDialog.Options options=0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_mainWindow'
```

So, ui_mainWindow is the class that all of my GUI buttons and the GUI itself is stored in.

```
class Ui_mainWindow(object):
```

I don't understand why I'm getting an error, does anyone have any ideas?

Here is a pastebin link to the entire GUI: http://pastebin.com/BWCcXxUW

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I understand, you are using `Ui_mainWindow` generated from `.ui` file. As you can see `Ui_mainWindow` is just python class which contains widgets. `getOpenFileName` recieves `QWidget` instance as first parameter. So you need to subclass `QWidget` or `QMainWindow` and define methods in that class.

Code will look like this:

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

from file_with_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def browse(self):
        filename = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File', '.')
        fname = open(filename)
        data = fname.read()
        self.textEdit.setText(data)
        fname.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Alternatively you can store `ui` as instance attribute:

```
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
         QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
         self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
         self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

And acces your controls through `self.ui`, e.g.: `self.ui.textEdit.setText(data)`

Consider reading tutorial about `pyuic` usage [PyQt by Example (Session 1)](http://lateral.netmanagers.com.ar/stories/BBS47.html)

Comment: Alright, thank you, I'll read that, I have another issue, I don't really know how to go about it. I'm new to classes and methods so bear with me.

Comment: I have a script that reads the files in the directory and then uploads them:
http://pastebin.com/fnZN1rwS
This is so i can upload every photo in the directory.
However, because I'm using a class, I don't know how i can return the variable directory from the method browse. i've tried return directory but it doesn't do anything. Also i tried searching but couldn't find anything relevant. http://pastebin.com/S57DHQfF
This is where i define directory from the browse method.

Comment: @Anteara, you can define `def upload(self, directory):...` in class  and add code from script to this function. Then in `browse` add call to `self.upload(directory)`. Also read [Python tutorial - 4.6. Defining Functions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Answer (score 9):

import the following:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
```

In class Ui_MainWindow(object), replace object with QWidget:

```
Ui_MainWindow(QWidget)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def browseFiles(self):
        text, placeholder = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Select file')
```

The way it worked out for me is to use `None`, rather than `self`, as self inherits the type of the window above it, which is expected to be None, but is given `QMainWindow` as a type.

I also unpacked the tuple it returns, since this function returns two objects to work with.

I hope this helps, perhaps someone else could explain this better, as to why it works.

**TLDR:** The function expects `None` as the first parameter, but inherits a `QmainWindow` as type, due to `self`.

Answer (score 0):

file = str(QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, "Select Directory"))